# Qt: How do I set a QLineEdit's validator in the designer?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm designing a UI at the moment, and I have a situation where I have a QLineEdit which I need to only accept integers.

I know how to set the validator to use QIntValidator in code. But I'd like to do this in the designer.

How can I set the QLineEdit's validator when using the designer?

Note: I don't want to use an input mask. An input mask and a validator function differently.

Comment: I dont think you can. Its a QObject so it has to be set up in code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you asking how to do it 100% through designer, or for a widget that was designed in designer?

You're going to need to do it at the code level no matter what, there is no way to do it directly in designer - not all functionality is exposed to it.

Out of curiosity, why not use a QSpinBox if you're getting purely an integer?  You could use a QSpinBox and set the buttonSymbols to NoButtons, and even specify a suffix & prefix of text if you want.  The end result looks and acts almost exactly like a QLineEdit, however is geared specifically for integer values.

Comment: Hmmm... seems you're right, unfortunately. Thanks for the tip on the QSpinBox; I didn't know you could hide the buttons.

Comment: Really inspiring hint of QSpinBox.