# How to allow QLineEdit from Designer to accept only integer in the range 0 to 255?

Tags: qt, qlineedit

QT version 5.1

I have 2 issues:

1) I am wondering is there is any way I can set  `QLineEdit` widget  to accept only integer in the range from **0 < x < 255** from **QT DESIGNER**. I guess Input Mask can do this thing for us but wondering how ?

2) Only if we can't set values from QT designer, then in that case I have to do it from the source code. For that in which files will i make the changes?

Below is brief description of my project:

i) I have designed a GUI on QT designer with lots of `QLineEdit` widgets and buttons, checkbox etc.

ii) I am aware that there is `QValidator` class exist which can solve my problem . I know how to use `QValidator` but wondering just in case if I can't  set validation of `QLineEdit` from Gui then I have to do it from source code. This is not a problem but where will I add my validation code in source code?

Should I add this  in the constructor of GUI?

Comment: I'd suggest to do it in code, using QIntValidator. Just call it where you do the setupUi() call (after it) http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qintvalidator.html Alternatively, use a QSpinBox (which would be the more natural choice)

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank  for your advice

Comment: maybe this can help  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994041/qt-how-do-i-set-a-qlineedits-validator-in-the-designer)